# react-hook-form and react-datetime: How to set the time to moment() from a button

Tags: react-hook-form, react-datetime

I am using [react-datetime](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datetime) inside a react-hook-form

[image]

I want the user to easily set the time to current time using a button `Immediate`. Instead of selecting the current time manually.

I am trying the below

```
const [currentDateTime, setcurrentDateTime] = useState(null);
<Controller
    name="resetDateTime"
    control={control}
    required
    render={({ field }) => (
        <Datetime
            onChange={setcurrentDateTime}
            inputProps={{
                placeholder: "MM-DD-YYYY HH:mm",
            }}
            value={currentDateTime}
            viewMode="time"
        />
    )}
/>
<Button color="primary" className="ml-1" onClick={() => setcurrentDateTime(moment())}>
    {"Immediate"}
</Button>
```

The problem is onSubmit the react-hook-form I get `resetDateTime = undefined`

How to implement this properly. So I can use the `Immediate` button and also submit form and get the `resetDateTime` value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing RHF with your local state `currentDateTime` and are not linking the. field to RHF as you're missing to spread the `field` object to your `<Datetime />` component.

The correct way would be to use RHF's `setValue` to update your `resetDateTime` field and get rid of the `useState` hook.

```js
const { control, handleSubmit, setValue } = useForm();
```

```js
<Controller
    name="resetDateTime"
    control={control}
    required
    render={({ field }) => (
        <Datetime
            {...field}
            inputProps={{
                placeholder: "MM-DD-YYYY HH:mm",
            }}
            viewMode="time"
        />
    )}
/>

<Button color="primary" className="ml-1" onClick={() => setValue("resetDateTime", moment())}>
    {"Immediate"}
</Button>
```